# SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync with Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I was working on implementing Identity and came across an interesting issue. The default implementation uses a Login method that uses the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync method. However, the implementation of PasswordSignInAsync requires a username parameter. Why is this or am I not understanding what’s going on? Thanks.

Comment: What is the confusion? Logical that you need a username and a password from a user to login. Users can also login with Google or Facebook, in that case the login will be without a password, hence the name.

Comment: The confusion is that the default code in AccountController is sending an email yet the implementation is expecting a username, which is not necessarily an email.

Answer (score 0):

By default, register action will set the email as email account and as username for the user account, this way, when you log in, when asked for username you'll post an email account.

The system is also prepared so is easy to you to change this behaviour, just allowing username and email to be different values on account register, and being able to login just through username/password.